# how to use "where not in" in sql ce database query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm working with SQL Server and SQL CE
I'm trying to make a simple subquery

```
Select * From Item_Lots where Distribution_Code NOT IN
(select Distribution_Code from Stock_Serials)
```

, but it doesn't work on SQL CE !!

Any work around for this ?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this works in SQL CE, but it is the standard way to replace a NOT IN SQL.

```
SELECT Item_Lots.*
FROM Item_Lots 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Stock_Serials
        ON Item_Lots.Distribution_Code = Stock_Serials.Distribution_Code 
WHERE Stock_Serials.Distribution_Code IS NULL
```

You can try also this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Item_Lots
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Stock_Serials
    WHERE Stock_Serials.Distribution_Code = Item_Lots.Distribution_Code 
)
```

Reference : [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but is Distribution_Code nullable?

I hit the same problem since = cannot do null comparisons in Sql Compact. Filtering out null values from the inner query solved this for me

```
SELECT * FROM Item_Lots WHERE Distribution_Code NOT IN
(SELECT Distribution_Code FROM Stock_Serials WHERE Distribution_Code IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Distribution_Code)
```